# Show that there exists a sequence $c_n\rightarrow \infty$ such that $\frac{X_n}{c_n}\rightarrow 0$ almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value

Let $(X_n)_n$ be a sequence of random variables. Show that there exists a sequence $c_n\rightarrow \infty$ such that $\frac{X_n}{c_n}\rightarrow 0$ almost surely. I am not sure how to start, may someone elaborate on the intuition to construct the $c_n's$? How would one sttart constructing them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $\frac{X_{n}}{c_{n}}\rightarrow 0$ almost surely](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913426/show-that-fracx-nc-n-rightarrow-0-almost-surely)

Comment: @GabrielRomon Can you give a complete solution?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $X_n/c_n\to 0$ a.s. if $\mathsf{P}(|X_n/c_n|>\epsilon_n\text{ i.o.})=0$, where $\{\epsilon_n\}$ is a positive sequence converging to $0$. Then, given $\{\epsilon_n\}$, choose a sequence $\{c_n\}$ s.t.
$$
\sum_{n\ge 1}\mathsf{P}(|X_n|>c_n\epsilon_n)<\infty.
$$

Comment: +1 even though I would expect that there is a more direct way (i.e. one without Borel-Cantelli).